# js/ajax w/ onkeypress with throttling

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, onkeyup

working on a dynamic request as a person types.
Would like to try to throttle it so not EVERY key press fires off a call.

First thought was to do a setimeout of 1s and clear the timeout with each keypress, therefore waiting till there is a lag of 1s before pushing off the request.

Wondering if there are any cleaner suggestions

Comment: No, I can't think of a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) Offers a throttle function that creates a version of a function that is executed only once every x milliseconds. You might want to look into that

Answer (score 0):

That solution will work well if you don't have a lot of other script that will run simultaneous.

Otherwise you can set up an `if` loop which triggers the call every 5 keypress for example.
Something like this:

```
if(i == 5) {
    //Execute your call
}
```

And then you you increase the value of i each time a key is pressed.

But of course there are even more solutions as well.

Comment: only downside I see on this is if they dont reach the threshold, then nothing triggers.

Comment: Of course, that is true. Didn't really reflect over what you were going to use it for. So then it's probably better to go with a timer.